# Populate Tableview by bool value from the Core Data database

Tags: ios, swift, core-data

I am fresh in iOS programming and trying to populate the Tableview with data from Coredata database thanks to Bool value, but I don't know how to set divided list in Tableview.

```
 private func setList() {
    var tasks = try? self.dataController.fetchActiveTasks()
    let request = Task.fetchRequest() as NSFetchRequest<Task>
    request.sortDescriptors = [NSSortDescriptor(key: "date", ascending: true)]
   
    let fetchController = NSFetchedResultsController(fetchRequest: request,
                                                     managedObjectContext: self.dataController.context,
                                                     sectionNameKeyPath: nil, cacheName: nil)
    fetchController.delegate = self
    self.fetchController = fetchController
    try? fetchController.performFetch()
}
}
```

The list called tasks works well. In the debug area I see list divided by false value, but can't figure out how to use it in my case.

Comment: Divided list, what is that? Do you mean you want to use sections in your table view and if so on what attribute do you want to use for grouping (dividing) your data?

Comment: The Model has a bool field. I want list only with false values.

Comment: Then you need a predicate for your request, research NSPredicate

Comment: Done! Thank you. But what if I want to use a list created in my own data controller? I mean there is a custom class which represents Coredata functions (save, delete, list etc.) and I want to use list from that class. How to set it up?